# Google Drive using wrong and weird icons for various file types

Tags: google-drive

I uploaded an .exe file (of a game) to my Google Drive, and noticed a strange icon used for it:

> [image: icon for .exe file in Google Drive]

What does this icon mean? Looks like email with play button...  but can't see how it's related to .exe file or even the game itself in case Google somehow sniffed the contents of the file.

I took a look in [Google Drive icons and buttons](https://sites.google.com/a/georgiasouthern.edu/google-apps-fac-staff/learn-more/drive/documents#TOC-Icons-in-Google-Drive-on-the-web) but didn't see that icon in there.

On a different Google account I have (used for work), there is a different icon for old .exe files:

> [image]

But when uploading the same .exe as above, I see the same icon.

What's going on? How Google decide which icon to assign, and do they have any special meaning, e.g. permissions?

I also uploaded .rdp ([Remote Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) connection file) and it's even worse, Google Drive thinks it's an audio file:

> [image: icon for .rdp file in Google Drive]

Double clicking it makes it try to play as audio, which of course fails. I didn't find anywhere how .rdp can be audio file.

Comment: Have you added Google Drive apps to your account? Ref. [Use Google Drive apps](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2500820?hl=en)

Comment: @Rubén only the default app coming as part of android.

Comment: Have you followed the link in my comment?

Comment: @Rubén yes it does not list any existing apps, in case it should, and I've never used it before.

Comment: An exe file that I loaded the last week shows a different icon, the one shown for the "some_exe" file on arieljannai answer.

Comment: @Rubén it becomes even more weird, I have the same with different account. Edited the question.

Comment: Do you mean that the envelope icon is showed on a consumer account (usually a gmail.com) but not on a G Suite account?

Comment: In the work account, when you upload icy tower - you get the blue icon or the envelope one? It wasn't clear for me from what you wrote

Comment: @arieljannai envelope.

Comment: The icons changed in my drive right now.. Still the same for you? Now the envelope has changed to a kind of list icon (3 vertical dots, horizontal line from each one)

Comment: @arieljannai yes, they changed for me too. So weird!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Can you still get the green icon? It doesn't seem to be anymore, in any situation

Comment: @arieljannai no, but other icons are weird too. :(

Comment: If you mean the icons you mentioned in the question - I believe I figured it out. About others - I don't know yet 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The icons represent the file type, recognized by its mime-type, extension, and encoding.

### Detailed explanation:

The green envelope icon no longer occur <sup>(1)</sup>, so about the others - **lets go:**

> What's going on? How Google decide which icon to assign, and do they have any special meaning, e.g. permissions?

- Google decides what the icon will be by its extension, encoding, and [mime-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type).

  - Icons examples by mime-type (recognized by Google Drive [from the html source]):

    - [`application/octet-stream`](https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/128/type/application/octet-stream) <sub>[image: application/octet-stream]</sub>.
    - [`application/x-msdownload`](https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/128/type/application/x-msdownload) <sub>[image: application/x-msdownload]</sub>.
    - [`application/x-dosexec`](https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/128/type/application/x-dosexec) <sub>[image]</sub>.
  - `x-dosexec` is a subtype of `x-msdownload`. The former is used specifically to `.exe` files, where the latter includes: `exe`, `dll`, `com`, `bat`, `msi` ([source](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types)).
- The meaning is their recognized mime-type, nothing to do with permissions.

> I also uploaded .rdp (Remote Desktop connection file) and it's even worse, Google Drive thinks it's an audio file

- In that case, the encoding of the rdp file created by the `Remote Desktop Connection` utility is (according to notepad++) `UCS-2 LE BOM`.

  - **UCS-2 LE BOM** explanation: [UTF-16 extends UCS-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), in [Little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) (=LE), and with [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

  It seems that there was a confusion by the browser or Google Drive in interpreting the encoding, which led Google Drive think it's an audio file.
- For example, here's the difference in hex between this encoding (left) to ANSI (right):

  [image]

<sup>(1)</sup> From previous tests, it seems that the green envelope icon was replaced by this icon: <sub>[image]</sub>.

---

***The old answer is partial and doesn't really explains much***.
It's kept here is a comment (choose `edit` to watch).

Comment: And the other some_exe? No extension at all? You give four files but only two explanations, it's unclear how you tested.

Comment: I clarified it a bit - now it's more understandable?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Still weird why they chose such an icon for an exe file, wonder if it's explained anywhere.

Comment: So far I haven't found an explanation. I agree with you that it's a strange choice of icon! 

Comment: It becomes even weirder, and worse... see my edit.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I re-wrote my answer, and I believe now it answers the question better. With proofs rather then assumptions :)

Comment: Thanks, guess I won't get a better answer. :)

Comment: If I'll figure something new I'll update the answer :)